# Select some specific data after inner join

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, join, inner-join

I'am combined 4 tables by using inner join and after that i want to select some of these datas from that combined table, 
for example sizes of shoes that which has model name as XX3. The product list after join process is below

[image]

How can i make this happen ? Any help would be appriciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you asking about filtering other records?

Use WHERE clause..

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.size,m.modelName
FROM
.
.
.
WHERE
  m.ModelName like '%XX3%'
ORDER BY m.ModelName
```

Comment: I'am trying to diplay shoes by using a repeater in my web page. For example by selecting the shoe color from combo box i want see the change of the picture for the current shoe. I'am planning to use AJAX for this and thats why i need a that type of query.

Comment: Good for you mate. Carry on.